# Mac OS X. No such file or directory for Lua framework

Tags: c++, cocoa, xcode, macos, lua

I have [Cocoa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_%28API%29) project which uses Lua.framework.

In the header file I try to include some .h files from this framework:

```
...
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>
...
```

And when I compile the source file I get this error:

```
error: lua.h: No such file or directory
error: lauxlib.h: No such file or directory
error: lualib.h: No such file or directory
```

Why does it happen?

Comment: @e40pud: what is "Lua.framework"? Do you have a link to it? Is it http://www.frykholm.se/luaframework.html ?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by rebuilding the Lua framework.